# Exception thrown in PyCharm debug mode but not in run mode (seaborn, matplotlib)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pycharm, seaborn

I'm using

- PyCharm 2021.2.3 Community Edition
- Python interpreter 3.10.0
- matplotlib 3.5.0
- seaborn 0.11.2
- numpy 1.21.4
- pandas 1.3.4
- PySimpleGUI 4.55.1

When I run the following script, it is fine in run mode but in debug mode it throws an exception. Here's the script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import seaborn as sns

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


def init_data():
    r1 = np.random.rand(5, 4)
    columns = [f"var{i}" for i in range(1, 5)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(r1, columns=columns)
    df.insert(0, 'year', range(2021, 2026))
    df.insert(1, 'scenario', 'test1')
    ldf = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['year', 'scenario'], value_vars=columns, var_name='percentile', value_name='carbon')
    return ldf


def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    return figure_canvas_agg


# define the window layout
layout = [[sg.Text('Plot test')],
          [sg.Canvas(key='-CANVAS-')],
          [sg.Button('Ok')]]

# create the form and show it without the plot
window = sg.Window('Testing seaborn in PySimpleGUI', layout, finalize=True,
                   element_justification='center', font='Helvetica 18')

figure = Figure()
ax = figure.subplots()
sns.lineplot(x='year', y='carbon', hue='percentile', data=init_data(), ax=ax)

# add the plot to the window
fig_canvas_agg = draw_figure(window['-CANVAS-'].TKCanvas, figure)

event, values = window.read()

window.close()
```

And here's the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 384, in __new__
    dtype = numeric.dtype(dtype)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/OneDrive/OneDrive - Louise Pryor & Co Ltd/Actuarial/Carbon/Carbon/seaborntest.py", line 39, in <module>
    sns.lineplot(x='year', y='carbon', hue='percentile', data=init_data(), ax=ax)
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py", line 46, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 710, in lineplot
    p.plot(ax, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py", line 557, in plot
    self._add_axis_labels(ax)
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_core.py", line 1194, in _add_axis_labels
    x_visible = any(t.get_visible() for t in ax.get_xticklabels())
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return get_method(self)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1249, in get_ticklabels
    return self.get_majorticklabels()
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1201, in get_majorticklabels
    ticks = self.get_major_ticks()
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1371, in get_major_ticks
    numticks = len(self.get_majorticklocs())
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1277, in get_majorticklocs
    return self.major.locator()
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 2113, in __call__
    vmin, vmax = self.axis.get_view_interval()
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1987, in getter
    return getattr(getattr(self.axes, lim_name), attr_name)
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 781, in viewLim
    self._unstale_viewLim()
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 776, in _unstale_viewLim
    self.autoscale_view(**{f"scale{name}": scale
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2932, in autoscale_view
    handle_single_axis(
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2895, in handle_single_axis
    x0, x1 = locator.nonsingular(x0, x1)
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 1654, in nonsingular
    return mtransforms.nonsingular(v0, v1, expander=.05)
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 2880, in nonsingular
    if maxabsvalue < (1e6 / tiny) * np.finfo(float).tiny:
  File "C:\Users\drlou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 387, in __new__
    dtype = numeric.dtype(type(dtype))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Has anyone seen this before or have any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue when calling the pandas dataframe.plot() function and scikit-learn's LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)...

Comment: Same, on Windows, using 64-bit:
- PyCharm 2021.3
- Python 3.10.1
- numpy 1.21.4
- pandas 1.3.5
- pandasgui 0.2.13

Repro code:
from pandasgui import show
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
show(df)

Comment: Experiencing the same with Windows; using 64-bit: PyCharm 2021.3 - Python 3.10.1 and matplotlib 3.5.1

Comment: Same here, triggered by 'from scipy import optimize', Win 10 64bit, PyCharm 2021.3, Python 3.10, pandas 1.3.4, numpy 1.21.4 (and also upgrade to 1.22.1)

Comment: Same when debugging a file from VSCode on Python v3.10

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

also for PyCharm 2021.3.3 and Python 3.10.2, pandas, matplotlib

Comment: I had downvoted accidentally and realizing a bit late now. I cannot undo my downvote, sorry for this :( @lpryor

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue until I changed my version of python from 3.10 to 3.9.5.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I ended up doing the same and this worked great for me

Comment: I changed my version of python from 3.10 to 3.9.5. this worked great for me thanks

Answer (score -1):

This did the ugly trick for debugging under pyCharm 2022.1.1, python 3.10.4, scipy=1.8.0
numpy=1.22.3
pandas=1.4.1

## AK lame handling of debugg issue with numpy vs pandas/scipy np.core.numeric.dtype

if sys.gettrace():
np.core.numeric.dtype = np.dtype